# How to get all possible partitions of a graph?

Tags: graph-theory

i have the following problem. Imagine a connected graph, like this:
[image]
How can i get all possible partitions of the nodes. Since not between all nodes is a direct edge, not all partitions in general (Bell number for number of Nodes) are possible. Is there any algorithm or at least idea to find a way to only inner connected partitions?
So the possible solutions for this example would be:

```
{p1, p2, p3}{p4}, 
{p1,p2}{p3, p4}, 
{p1,p3}{p2}{p4}...
```

Comment: `Since not between all nodes is a direct edge, not all partitions in general (Bell number for number of Nodes) are possible.` What does this sentence mean?

Comment: That the following partition is not possible: {p1,p3}{p2,p4} since p2 and p4 are not connected and can therefore not be in the same partition

Comment: https://patterns.eecs.berkeley.edu/?page_id=571#Partitioning_Algorithms